# WebSocket operation cannot be performed after the response has been submitted

Tags: c#, http, websocket, handshake

I have encountered a problem etabilising a web socket connection via APIController.
I'm upgrading a HTTP request to a different protocol, and it works absolutely fine.

```
var owinContext = Request.GetOwinContext();
var acceptToken = owinContext.Get<WebSocketAccept>("websocket.Accept");
if (acceptToken != null)
{
    SocketConnection.Setter(tenantId);
    acceptToken(null, SocketConnection.Process);
}
else
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
```

Its possible to open the connection and close it properly without any problems.
The problem occur when I'm checking for for the **WebSocketReceiveResult**, so I know when to close my connection.

```
public static async Task Process(IDictionary<string, object> websocketContext)
{
    object value;
    System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket socket = null;

    if (websocketContext.TryGetValue(typeof(WebSocketContext).FullName, out value))
    {
        socket = ((WebSocketContext)value).WebSocket;
    }        

    var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);

    while (socket != null && socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        WebSocketReceiveResult result;
        do
        {
            // The following line
            result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

        } while (!result.EndOfMessage);

        if (result.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Close) continue;

        await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", CancellationToken.None);
    }     
}
```

When I perform this action this problem occurs:

**This operation cannot be performed after the response has been submitted**.